# IGrouping ElementAt vs. square bracket operator

Tags: c#, igrouping

`IGrouping` supports the `ElementAt` method to index into the grouping's collection.  So why doesn't the square bracket operator work?

I can do something like

```
 list.GroupBy(expr).Select(group => group.ElementAt(0)....)
```

but not

```
 list.GroupBy(expr).Select(group => group[0]....)
```

I'm guessing this is because the IGrouping interface doesn't overload the square bracket operator.  Is there a good reason why IGrouping *didn't* overload the square bracket operator to do the same thing as `ElementAt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit back to front, all enumerables are supported by (rather than supports, as it's an extension method provided from the outside) `ElementAt()` but only some are of a type that also support `[]`, such as `List<T>` or anything that implements `IList<T>`.

`Grouping` certainly could implement `[]` easily enough, but then it would have to always do so, as the API would be a promise it would have to keep on keeping, or it would break code written to the old way if it did break it.

`ElementAt()` takes a test-and-use approach in that if something supports `IList<T>` it will use `[]` but otherwise it counts the appropriate number along. Since you can count-along with any sequence, it can therefore support any enumerable.

It so happens that `Grouping` does support `IList<T>` but as an explicit interface, so the following works:

```
//Bad code for demonstration purpose, do not use:
((IList<int>)Enumerable.Range(0, 50).GroupBy(i => i / 5).First())[3]
```

But because it's explicit it doesn't have to keep supporting it if there was ever an advantage found in another approach.

The test-and-use approach of `ElementAt`:

```
public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) return list[index];
    if (index < 0) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
            if (index == 0) return e.Current;
            index--;
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore gets the optimal O(1) behaviour out of it, rather than the O(n) behaviour otherwise, but without restricting `Grouping` to making a promise the designers might later regret making.

Comment: This makes sense now.  To summarize: `ElementAt` is an extension method of `IEnumerable`, `IGrouping` extends `IEnumerable` and thus inherits `ElementAt`, but the indexed property (Item) is unique to `IList` and not available in `IGrouping`.  The concrete class from `GroupBy` *does* implement `IList` but that is not guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: Pretty much. *Inherits* is poor wording, since that suggests it's inherited from a base, whereas extension methods are actually static methods that can be called with a syntax that makes calling them look like calling instance methods. Apart from that niggle, yes.

Answer (score 2):

That is because GroupBy returns an [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). IEnumerables don't have an indexing accessor

Comment: more precisely, GroupBy returns a collection of IGrouping, which extends IEnumerable

Answer (score 2):

`ElementAt<T>` is a standard extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, it's not a method on `IGrouping`, but since `IGrouping` derives from `IEnumerable<T>`, it works fine. There is no [] extension method because it's not supported by C# (it would be an indexed property, not a method)

Answer (score 0):

`ElementAt` is an **extension method** (btw highly inefficient) defined for `IEnumerable<T>` to provide a pseudo-indexed access for the sequences that do not natively support it. Since `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` returned from a `GroupBy` method inherits `IEnumerable<TElement>`, you can use `ElementAt` method. But of course `IEnumerable<T>` does not have an indexer defined, so thta's why you cannot use `[]`.

**Update:** Just to clarify what I meant by "highly inefficient" - the implementation is the best that could be provided, but the method itself in general for the sequences that do not natively support indexer. For example

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000);
for (int i = 0, count = source.Count(); i < count; i++)
{
    var element = source.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything inherently inefficient about the implementation of ElementAt ([reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761)) - in fact if the `IEnumerable` implements `IList` then the lists Indexer is used.

Comment: @Rob I meant that for sequences that do not support indexer, it's a O(N^2) time complexity to access each element by index.